# nuclear $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $(A_i)$ is a sequence of nuclear $C^*$ algebras,Is $\oplus_{c_0}A_i$ ($c_0$ direct sum)and $\prod A_i$($\ell ^\infty $ direct sum) also nuclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $a\in \bigoplus_nA_n$ and $\varepsilon>0$. For each $n$, there exist ucp maps $\varphi_n:A_n\to M_{k(n)}(\mathbb C)$ and $\psi_\varepsilon:M_{k(n)}(\mathbb C)\to A_n$ such that $\|\psi_n\circ\varphi_n(a_n)-a_n\|<\varepsilon$. 
There is also $m$ such that $\|a_n\|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq m$. Write $a_0$ for the truncation of $a$ to its first $m$ entries; then $\|a-a_0\|<\varepsilon$. Then the maps 
$$
\varphi:\bigoplus_nA_n\to \bigoplus_{n=1}^mM_{k(n)}(\mathbb C),\ \ \ \psi:\bigoplus_{n=1}^mM_{k(n)}(\mathbb C)\to \bigoplus_nA_n
$$
given by $$\varphi(b)=\bigoplus_{n=1}^m\varphi_n(b_n),\ \ \ \ \ \psi(\bigoplus_{n=1}^m c_n)=\bigoplus_{n=1}^m \psi_n(c_n)$$
satisfy 
\begin{align}
\|\psi\circ\varphi(a)-a\|
&\leq\|\psi\circ\varphi(a)-\psi\circ\varphi(a_0)\|+\|\psi\circ\varphi(a_0)-a_0\|+\|a_0-a\|\\ \ \\
&\leq 2\|a_0-a\|+\|\psi\circ\varphi(a_0)-a_0\|<3\varepsilon. 
\end{align}
By making this work over the finite sets $F\subset \bigoplus_nA_n$ we obtain net $\{\varphi_F\}$ and $\{\psi_F\}$ such that $\|\psi_F\circ\varphi_F(a)-a\|\to0$ for all $a\in \bigoplus_nA_n$.

The diret product, on the other hand is not nuclear; it's not even exact. For instance $M=\prod_n M_n(\mathbb C)$ is not nuclear. It is well-known that nuclear algebras are exact, and that exactness passes to subalgebras. The full C$^*$-algebra of $\mathbb F_2$ is known to be non-exact, and to be *residually finite*; this means that there exists a faithful representation $\pi:C^*(\mathbb F_2)\to M=\prod_nM_n(\mathbb C)$. So $M$ cannot be exact, and in particular it is not nuclear.

Comment: Exsctly. $\ \ $

Comment: Do you mean "the universal $C^\ast$ algebra of $\mathbb F_2$", right? The reduced $C^\ast$-algebra is exact and simple, therefore can not be residually finite.

Comment: @Adríán: indeed, thanks for noticing.